# How to use Asp.net 1.1 webrequest like java apache httpclient?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, parsing

I am new in asp.net and I have asp.net 1.1 in my server. 
I want to do in background --> login to another site and navigate in it <-- to retrieve some information needed to process in my page.

With Apache httpclient I can maintain the login session at background and navigate how much time I need and get elements by id, class, name (td,tr,etc) with Jsoup (a parser)

Until now I can just retrieve the whole code from the other page with that, but when I try to go to other page using CookieContainer it still doesn't work:
I did this example to show what I trying to do..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.4shared.com/web/login/validate");

  req.Method = "POST";
  req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
  req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
  req.KeepAlive = true;
  req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
  req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

  req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

  req.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

  String Username = "user%40email.com";
  String PassWord = "password";


  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
  sw.Write("login=" + Username + "&password=" + PassWord);
  sw.Close();

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1255));
  string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();






  HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.4shared.com/account/home.jsp");
  req2.Method = "GET";
  req2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
  req2.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
  req2.KeepAlive = true;
  req2.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
  req2.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

  req2.ContentType = "text/html";

  HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse();

  StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1255));
  string tmp2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();

  response2.Close();
  Panel2.Text = tmp2;
```

}

I need to retrieve the page login and show a captcha, and then POST with login info, and after that navigate to get some necessary to process in my page.

What I can't do is navigate to another page. And before that get some elements from response.

Comment: Why are you using a 12-year-old version of the framework?

Comment: You're looking for `CookieContainer` and HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: CookieContainer doesn't work in my case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compare your requests to requests from a real browser in Fiddler & see what's different.

Comment: Now I can login and navigate, in the example the login like was wrong. What is lacking is get a captcha to the user that will type and then do the process on background. Is it possible?